# PLS-00103 error for trigger

Tags: plsql

This trigger is supposed to throw an error if a price increase of more than 10% occurs. For some reason I receive the PLS-00103 error.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER product_price_updt
BEFORE UPDATE ON PRODUCT
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
price_error VARCHAR2(100);
BEGIN
IF (:new.price > :old.price * 1.1) THEN raise price_error;
END IF;
EXCEPTION 
when price_error then ('Price increase is greater than 10%, update cancelled');
END;
```

This is what I see when I compile it.

```
Error(7,78): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ")" when expecting one of the following:     * & = - + < / > at in is mod remainder not rem    <an exponent (**)> <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or like like2    like4 likec as between || multiset member submultiset
```

Perhaps my syntax is wrong and the error is misleading. I'm unable to find the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RAISE must be used with an EXCEPTION - here you're using it with a VARCHAR2 argument, which is  one issue.  The other I can see is that in your exception block you've got a string ('Price increase is greater than 10%, update cancelled') where you need some sort of function call.  I suggest rewriting your trigger as:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER product_price_updt
  BEFORE UPDATE ON PRODUCT
  FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  price_error EXCEPTION;
BEGIN
  IF (:new.price > :old.price * 1.1) THEN
    raise price_error;
  END IF;
EXCEPTION 
  when price_error then
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Price increase is greater than 10%, update cancelled');
END product_price_updt;
```

Share and enjoy.

Comment: Ah, I came across some old tutorials and they had declared the exception as varchar2. Thank you very much, that was it!

Comment: Those tutorials may have been using the RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR procedure to raise an exception.  I suggest you find that in the docs and read up on it.  Share and enjoy.